# Install GUI(Unity) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04

I've create a ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine on Google cloud.

And I've tried to use the following command to install.

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

But when I reboot, it doesn't get in the GUI.

Did I missed something?

Comment: So , this is not a local machine ? you connect to it via SSH ?

Comment: Yes, I use the SSH button on the webpage.
@Serg

Comment: OK , probably delete that comment. Too much information there. What you have there is a remote server. Typically , you don't use GUI with remote servers, but from your local computer you should be able to do `ssh -X user@ip_address` , and then run `startx` or `sudo service lightdm restart` .  But please note: GUI on remote Ubuntu server is bad idea, as it's a possible attack vector for blackhat hackers.

Comment: @Serg 
The reason I'm doing that, is just because I'm a noob in this area, and just want to try out the latest cloud things, feel what it feels like.
I've tried to login using below code.
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key [USERNAME]@[IP_ADDRESS]`
And I've tried starx(he told me to install xinit), and then it says 
`unable to connect to X server: Connection refused`.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo startx`? You can also change this behaviour with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common`, so that you needn't be `root`.